# PHP dynamic input tag

Tags: php, yii2

I am creating a Quiz app and the questions are saved in the database. The number of questions per quiz is indefinite. Here is the ERD.
[image]

Using this ERD, I can display the questions for a certain quiz just like following code:

```
$questions= select * from questions where quiz_id=$quizid;
foreach($questions as $q){
   echo "<input type='text' name='input".$q->quiz_id."'>"
}
```

So the name of the inputted value is `input` plus the `question id` just like `input1`. If there are 5 questions the submitted values should be from `input1` to `input5`.

[image]

**How do I able to capture the submitted values in post method in such a way that I can be able to save it in the answers table?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the name input of fields as an array element.

```
$questions= select * from questions where quiz_id=$quizid;
foreach($questions as $key=>$q){
echo "<input type='text' name='input[".$key."]'>"
}
```

now you can get all the inputs value in an array.

```
$input = $_POST['input'];
```

Comment: OMG. Got stuck in this problem this whole day. I cannot imagine that my problem is just so simple to solve. Thanks.